# how to zip file from list after getting from storage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

How to zip file after getting from storage.I am using the flutter archiver package unzip work fine but the zip not working.

```
return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                leading: Image.file(files[index]),

           //      trailing: Text(),
                onTap: () async {
                  var folderName = 'fayzo.zip';
                  final sourceDir = Directory("storage/emulated/0/$folderName");
                   files = [
                    File(sourceDir.path + files[index].path),
                    File(sourceDir.path + files[index].path)
                  ];

                  final zipFile = File(files[index]);
                  try {
                    ZipFile.createFromFiles(
                        sourceDir: sourceDir, files: files, zipFile: zipFile);
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
              ));
```

Comment: what error it throwing?

Comment: can you plz edit the code files[index] is the path of file on which i tap. and i want to create a new directory zip files and save zip file there